# FirebaseAnimatedList doesn't return anything

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write an app that will detect Barcode ID. Once detected, it will fetch value in my Firebase Database and display them inside my Widget. I want my widget to be dynamic since i don't know how many items could be inside each ID. So i tried using **FirebaseAnimatedList** class. Issue is i can't get my Widget show up in my page at all.

Here's my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:logistec/widget/result_page/productlist.dart';

class Scanning_Result_Page extends StatefulWidget {
  Scanning_Result_Page(this.phyid, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  String phyid;

  @override
  State<Scanning_Result_Page> createState() => _Scanning_Result_PageState();
}


class _Scanning_Result_PageState extends State<Scanning_Result_Page> {
  late String productcode;
  late String productname;
  late int quantity;
  late Query _ref =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Database').child(widget.phyid);

//firebase structure currently goes like this
//PHYID
//|---number
//|-----items_name
//|-----items_codes etc...
//Therefore i need it to first fetch PHYID
//then after that, use for loop from 0 to the full lenght of that ID
//


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(40, 40),
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber.shade400,
          )),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          query: _ref.equalTo(widget.phyid),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
              Animation<double> animation, int index) {
            Map database = snapshot.value as Map;
            if (database != null) {
              //result = key - phyid | value - 0?
              return ProductList(
                productcode: 'Test 1', //will change this later. just need it to work for now.
                productname: 'Test 1',
                serial: 'Test 1',
                quantity: 1,
                phyid_result: widget.phyid,
              );
            } else {
              return Text("no data");
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my Widget page. (I don't think it's related to my issue but i'll include them regardless.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductList({
    Key? key,
    required this.productcode,
    required this.productname,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.phyid_result,
    required this.serial,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String productcode;
  final String productname;
  final int quantity;
  final String phyid_result;
  final String serial;
  //The Look in my head
  //Each Container will have
  ///////////////////////////////////
  ///ProductCode                    /
  ///ProductName                    /
  ///                               /
  /// ///////////////////////////////
  ///                       Quantity/
  /// ///////////////////////////////
  final appBar = AppBar();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 70.0,
                child: Text(
                  phyid_result,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: screenSize.size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade600)),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Column(
                    //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Text(
                          productcode,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        width: screenSize.size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                strokeAlign: StrokeAlign.inside)),
                        child: Text(
                          productname,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        width: screenSize.size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                strokeAlign: StrokeAlign.inside)),
                        child: Text(
                          serial,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Flexible(
                          fit: FlexFit.loose,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 90,
                            child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border:
                                      Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Quantity : \n\v${quantity}',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Scaffold part works. But everything inside **FirebaseAnimated** List all the way to **CircularProgressIndicator** doesn't work at all. It didn't even return if else statement. Just empty blank page with Scaffold.

The Widget itself will work fine if i remove everything out, and return only the ProductList widget itself. I tried searching on Google and didn't find anyone having issue like me. So i think i'm stuck. Does anyone know what could be the issue? Thanks for the assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So i solve my own issue.

It turns out that my Widget is the actual root cause. I don't think SliverList is playing well with FirebaseAnimatedList (maybe because they are doing essentially the same thing?) So i refactor and remove everything related to SliverList.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Container(
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade600)),
      child: Column(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Text(
              productcode,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            width: screenSize.size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    strokeAlign: StrokeAlign.inside)),
            child: Text(
              productname,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            width: screenSize.size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    strokeAlign: StrokeAlign.inside)),
            child: Text(
              serial,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 90,
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Text(
                      'Quantity : \n\v${quantity}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Then i reimplemented it into my pages. Now it works as expected. all is well again!